# Matplotlib scatter plot with unknown error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am attempting to create a scatter plot. I have a list of numbers from 0 - 17 as well as an array with 18 values. I can plot the data as a line plot but when I try to plot as a scatter, I get an error message I do not understand:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

What does this error message mean and how can I get the data to plot as a scatter?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [7316.0, 7453.25, 7518.25, 7711.5, 7448.0, 7210.25, 7416.75, 6960.75, 
     7397.75, 6397.5, 5522.75, 5139.0, 5034.75, 4264.75, 5106.0, 3489.5, 
     4712.0, 4770.0]
x = np.arange(0,18,1)

plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
plt.figure(1)
plt.xlim(0, 20)
plt.ylim(0, 10000)
plt.scatter(x, y, 'r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Check the [scatter documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter). Third argument is for size of points and should be scalar or array_like. I assume `'r'` is for color so do the following:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c='r')
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense now. I was reading it but omitting the c= portion as it is unnecessary in normal plots. It seems silly to have different syntax between the two styles.

Answer (score 0):

The third positional argument of `plot()` is `fmt=` which takes strings of the format `'[marker][line][color]'` so that each of lines, colors, and markers can be formatted in one go. If you omit line, it becomes a scatter plot. For example, the following two plot the same graph:

```py
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro');

plt.scatter(x, y, color='r');
```